# Function to Download External Images to My Site

Tags: functions, custom-field

I display images on my site from other sites. The URL is saved in a custom field named `couv`.

I would like to download these pictures on to my site and create a new custom field with the new value `couv2`.

I tried to do this with the following code in my `functions.php` file but it doesn't work.

```
function downloadcouv() {
    global $wp_query;
    $lien = get_post_meta(
        $wp_query->queried_object->ID,
        "couv",
        true
    );
    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
    $reg = "#([^/]*)$#";
    $chaine = $lien;
    preg_match( $reg, $chaine, $res );
    $couv = $uploads['baseurl'] . '/couv/' . $res[1];
    copy( $lien, $couv );
    add_post_meta(
        $wp_query->queried_object->ID,
        "couv2",
        $couv,
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'downloadcouv' );
```

Edit: I made this change but it is still not working.

```
function downloadcouv() {
    global $wp_query;
    $post_id = $wp_query->queried_object->ID;
    $lien = get_post_meta(
        $post_id,
        "couv",
        true
    );
    $desc = $post_title; 
    $couv = media_sideload_image(
        $lien,
        $post_id,
        $desc
    );
    add_post_meta(
        $post_title,
        "couv2",
        $couv,
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'downloadcouv' );
```

Comment: Take a look at [`media_sideload_image()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image).

Comment: I change it like this, but no way... `function downloadcouv() {
global $wp_query;
$post_id = $wp_query->queried_object->ID;
$lien = get_post_meta($post_id, "couv", true);
$desc = $post_title;
$couv = media_sideload_image($lien, $post_id, $desc);
add_post_meta($post_title, "couv2", $couv, true);
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'downloadcouv' );`

Comment: media_sideload_image() is to download an image from the specified URL and attach it to a post. But i don't want to use this image as a featured image. Just display it in post_id sidebar. I've got another image for featured image.

Comment: Please add additional efforts as [edit]s to your question. That's not readable as comment.

Comment: I've just edit my question. Sorry !

Comment: I fixed the code readability for you. Please take this as example for further questions – the easier to read, the better and more answers you will get. Aside from that, _"I change it like this, but no way…"_ is hardly an error description. No one sees your screen or will replicate your setup. Please be a bit more verbose. Just imagine you know nothing about your problem, then read your question and try to think what you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to upload a copy of the image saved as a URL in a custom field into a local directory on your site. This will not add the image to the media library and is meant as more of a caching mechanism.

You should always be sure that you have permission to use images from other sources before you use them. **Only use this code for good!**

```
function downloadcouv( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    // Update the post's metadata.

    if ( isset( $_POST['couv'] ) ) {

        // Get the upload directory
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

        // Make sure that the image URL is actually a URL
        if ( FALSE !== filter_var($_POST['couv'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ) {

            // Get the file extension
            $ext = pathinfo($_POST['couv'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            // Copy the file from the url to a local directory
            copy( $backdrop, $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/site-img-' . $post_id . '.' . $ext );

            // Update the post meta with the URL to the uploaded image
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'couv2', $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/site-img-' . $post_id . '.' . $ext );

        }

    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'downloadcouv', 10, 3 );
```